# Release the plugin in the WordPress repository where redux is used

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, theme-development, plugin-repository

I am developing a plugin for the WordPress repository.

I'm going to use redux for the settings.

**redux is a wordpress option managment plugin.** https://wordpress.org/plugins/redux-framework/

But I do not want to install redux as a user plugin. And I want it to be part of the core of my plugin.

Can I publish the plugin to the repository?

Comment: I'm a little confused, Redux is not a plugin, it's a javascript library, can you clarify? Keep in mind that only the .org plugin reviewers can give you a 100% certain answer on this though they too may struggle to understand, use the `Edit` link to update your question using different words so that your meaning is clearer

Comment: The question was edited. Thanks for your hint

Answer (score 1):

If you try to bundle a copy of another plugin inside your plugin it will be rejected. It would be better to disable your plugins functionality and throw up a prompt indicating that the redux framework plugin needs to be installed.

Even then this may not be allowed as your plugin sounds more like an add-on than a standalone plugin, they may see this as a problem.

To get a 100% certain answer though on what you should do instead, you will need to ask the plugin reviewers directly, rather than on this stack.